# Flutter VS Code Quick Fix not suggesting import

Tags: flutter, intellisense, dart-analyzer

Everything worked fine until a couple of days ago. Whenever I create new widgets or create some files and want to use them, I don't manually type `import package:...` but start typing the name of that class and press `ctrl + .` which provided a list of `Quick fix`es and always suggested `import package:...` until recently. No changes to Windows / Flutter / Dart / VS Code have been made except I installed [svg-explorer-extension](https://github.com/tibold/svg-explorer-extension/releases) after following [this advice](https://superuser.com/a/444145) (which I would highly doubt affected anything, yet it still updated some x64 c++ distribution something).

Right now, as I try to use existing files (all of them are in */lib folder) in the new files I create, the `Quick fix` menu provides all except `import package:...` options which makes the development process slow enough to ask a question here.

[image]

The only way to 'recover' that functionality is to run `Developer: Reload Window` in VS Code which stops the debug session, restarts `Dart Analyzer`, and everything seems to be okay for the next couple of minutes until it simply disappears.

How to not 'lose' that importing functionality? My project is rather big (22k lines) with 30+ dependencies. I tried reinstalling flutter SDK, flutter, and dart extensions from VS Code and that didn't help.

What suggestions do you have? Is this issue worth filing an issue for Flutter / Dart / Flutter Extension on GitHub?

Comment: I am also suffering from the same issue, it happens once in a while in Android studio, and much frequently in VS code

Comment: @Bensal, do you have a shareable code that we could use to post an issue on GitHub for the developers to take a look at?

Comment: This issue doesnot depend on the code, i had two projects and the problem was found in both. I think the issue is with flutter, dart or vs code

Comment: Have you ran any CCleaner / Registry editor or have you invalidated cache (or cleared it) from your machine? I wonder if that's what's done that.

Comment: I posted an issue for Dart Analyzer https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44321

Comment: Still facing this problem in 2022

Comment: Has anybody found any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried adding `"checkJs":true` to your `jsconfig.json` file?

Comment: I haven't touched code for quite a while so if anybody can test that and confirm if it's working, that'd be awesome!

Comment: Run Dart: Restart Analysis Server in Command Palette.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't find your import with the "Quick Fix" options, here is what you should do :

1. **Try running `flutter pub get`**
2. If it doesn't work, reload your window (Ctrl+Alt+P / Cmd+Alt+P and'Reload window')

I recommend to try to get your dependencies firstly, because reloading window generally kills you app.

Comment: Thanks for digging into it! As I no longer develop with Flutter, I would appreciate it if somebody else could confirm it's working by thumbing-up this solution. If it gets enough proof, I will confirm it as the correct one.

Comment: you are right, i had wrong line spacing in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 1):

Happening with recently and was fixed with the restart to update option.
It was so annoying and wasted my 1 hour searching over google and StackOverflow.

Answer (score -4):

I was also stucked in this issue and the real answer to this question according to my analysis is : always create new widgets or dart classes within lib folder. You can create different folders such as widgets, screens, models but always create them in lib folder dont create them at the root level. Your problem of import will be solved. Infact VSCode will auto-import them

You can refer to this image below and see how I organized my lib folder
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yau5i.png

Comment: unfortunately it's not the case. All the `.dart` files are under the `lib` folder, so this does not solve the issue.

Comment: Please read the question carefully posted by the OP

Comment: Run Dart: Restart Analysis Server in Command Palette.