# Unable to import anything on flutter in VSCode

Tags: flutter

I am learning flutter and start making items from the scratch but I am unable to import anything

I tried `flutter pub get` nothing works

Tried `Ctrl + Alt + P` -> `Developer: Window Reload` not working still

Tried Restarting the Application manually still the same

I am unable to import anything such simple.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try command

`flutter clean build`

then

`flutter pub get`

This usually solves such problems.

Comment: It does not let me show on on the dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the version of Flutter using Following Command :

**flutter upgrade**

Also Run this command :
flutter doctor
flutter --version

Also Update Your IDE to latest one...

Comment: if it is working then mark as done so that others people also get answers from this Question..... Or if it's not working then check for this link  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939202/flutter-vs-code-quick-fix-not-suggesting-import

Comment: Does not work, the import does not even display on the dropdown list